# FFmpeg "Pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input" TGA files

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, tga

I've run into a problem when using FFmpeg to process TGA files into an MP4 file. This is a version of what I'm doing that demonstrates the problem.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -r 60 -codec targa -i pipe:0 -r 60 -vf "tblend=average,framestep=2,tblend=average,framestep=2,tblend=average,framestep=2,setpts=0.125" -vcodec h264 -preset slow -crf 18 "Z:\path\to\final.mp4" < "Z:\path\to\image.tga"
```

Gives this error:

`ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '60'.
Reading option '-codec' ... matched as option 'codec' (codec name) with argument 'targa'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'pipe:0'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '60'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'tblend=average,framestep=2,tblend=average,framestep=2,tblend=average,framestep=2,setpts=0.125'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'h264'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'slow'.
Reading option '-crf' ... matched as AVOption 'crf' with argument '18'.
Reading option 'Z:\path\to\final.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url pipe:0.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 60.
Applying option codec (codec name) with argument targa.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: pipe:0.
[pipe @ 0000000000727f40] Setting default whitelist 'crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000001fcb3e0] Statistics: 1048576 bytes read, 0 seeks
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

### The actual implementation:

I have an external program that outputs TGA files, and I want to use Java to read those files, send them to FFmpeg, and then delete the files.

Comment: What is Java doing with the files - simply relaying them as-is? Then add `-f image2pipe` before `-i`  And replace the first `-r 60` with `-framerate 60`

Comment: Yes, it's just opening a FileInputStream and then using ByteStream.copy() to push it to the pipe. And with the changes, it now says "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Comment: Run the command with `-report` added and upload the generated logfile.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VMDzmVTw

Comment: Add `-probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M` before `-i` and remove `-f h264`.

Comment: Didn't change. https://pastebin.com/i3LtUWSZ

Comment: How large are the TGAs?

Comment: About 6 Megabytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a lack of a TARGA parser, only fixed file size TGAs (i.e. no RLE compression) can be piped into ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 60 -vcodec targa -frame_size 6220844 -i pipe:0 ... "final.mp4" < image.tga
```

The frame_size value should be the file size, in bytes, of your TARGA files.